# Running root service in Dockerfile with non-root user

Tags: bash, docker, cron, dockerfile, root

I am working on trying to make a non-root container and to run a `cron` task within the container. However the issue I am having is to make sure the serivce `cron` runs after being installed.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y bash nano cron 
RUN adduser --disabled-password -gecos '' -u 1551 face
RUN service cron start
USER 1551
```

After running the container and accessing it interactive, the service `cron` is not running:

```
face@9eb7bacb90ca:/$ service cron status
 * cron is not running
```

How can I make sure that the `cron` service is running within the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 4):

The `RUN` directive executes commands during the image build process.

Your `RUN service cron start` command isn't doing anything useful. Even if it successfully starts the `cron` service, the entire build environment goes away as soon as your image build is complete.

If you want a process to run in a container started from your image, you have to arrange to start that service via an appropriate `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` declaration, which sets commands that run when the container starts.

For example, something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y cron
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

You'll note that I've droped your `adduser` command (and the `USER` directive) from this example, because `cron` won't run as an unprivileged user.

If you start a container from this image, it will run the `cron` daemon. It won't be terribly useful by itself; if you want to update your question with more information about your goals I'd be happy to expand on this answer.

Comment: Hi @arsks, thanks for your answar. In your example the container will be running as root, which is something I am trying to fix by creating a user. However the issue is the `cron` service not running. I want to make sure the `cron` service is running in the container as root. However the container is not running as root.

Comment: There's not really a distinction between "the container" and "the single process running in the container": if the cron daemon needs to run as root, then "the container" is running as root.